# Having trouble to sum values in a column that match a given condition

Tags: python, pandas, oop, sum, operation

I am trying to sum the numeric values of one column depending on the value of another column. For example: whenever in the first column there is a `Glovoapp` I would like to sum its corresponding numeric values (of another column) together.

Table example:

| Initiator | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Glovoapp | 566 |
| XXXXX | 545 |
| Glovoapp | 899 |
| XXXXX | 200 |

```
montant_init = new_data.loc[new_data['Initiateur'] == 'Glovoapp', 'Price'].sum()

output: 0 (none)
expected output (example): 1465
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
montant_init = df[df["Initiator"]=="Glovoapp"]["Price"].sum()
```

Alternatively you can use groupby if you have multiple Initiators:

```
price_sum = df.groupby("Initiator")["Price"].sum()
```

output:

```
Initiator
Glovoapp    1465
XXXXX        745
```

Then

```
price_sum["Glovoapp"]
```

outputs:

```
1465
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I will use the groupby alternative. I appreciate your help a lot, I will accept the answer as soon as I am allowed to :D

Comment: No worries, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

I would write it this way:

```
montant_init = (
    new_data
    [new_data['Initiateur'] == 'Glovoapp']
    ['Montant (centimes)']
    .sum()
)
```